# LaTeX formulas after load html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, latex, mathjax

i want to load the `script` of `Mathjax`after using

```
( 'div#someone' ).load( "http source" )
```

Actually, it works perfectly when the page is fully loaded with it in the header.

```
<script class="mathlab" type="text/x-mathjax-config">MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [["$","$"], ["\\(","\\)"]]}});</script>
<script class="mathlab" type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
```

Anyone know how to refresh the script after load ? Or maybe another script ?

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}});</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">
    $("button").click(function() {
         $("div").text( "Hello ! What is $x$ in the formula : $$x+3=7$$" );
    });
</script>
```

```html
Hello ! What is $x$ in the formula : $$x+3=7$$
<div> <button>Load something</button> </div>
```

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add

```
$( "div#someone" ).load( "http source", function () {
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, "div#someone"]);
});
```